# Optimal one-shot input for $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes n}$ and optimal one-shot input for $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes k}$ where $k< n$?

Tags: information-theory, channel-capacity, max-entropy

Suppose I have a classical or quantum channel $\mathcal{N}$. I wish to use it for some communication task in the one-shot setting i.e. where I have $n$ i.i.d. copies of $\mathcal{N}$ denoted by $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes n}$. The result is usually some entropic quantity evaluated on an optimal input probability distribution/quantum state $\rho^{n}$.

Notice that $\rho^n$ is invariant under permutations among the $n$ registers. This is because if $\rho^n$ is permuted, there exists a decoder that just undoes the permutation after the action of $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes n}$.

Suppose I now have fewer copies of the channel $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes k}$ for $k< n$. There exists again a permutation invariant $\rho^k$ that is the optimal input distribution/input quantum state.

Is $\rho^k$ related to $\rho^n$ in some way? For instance, is it obtained by just tracing out the remaining $n-k$ registers? My goal is to use some finite de Finetti theorems to express $\rho^k$ and in order to this, I need to express $\rho^k$ as the marginal of some permutation-invariant state in higher dimension.